# how to save selected rows on UITableView using core data in objective c

Tags: ios

**How to save selected row,after clicking save button using Core data.**

I have static array value 1 to 40,this value display on UITableView. After that I selected row save on Core data.I don't know how to save selected row in core data. If any one know means solve the problem.

**These are array value.**

```
self.fetchedArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1.Check if the sump is clean",@"2.Check if pump works properly",@"3.Sump ball valve works",@"4.Water drains properly at the entrance",@"5.check if connecting drain pipes from home to main lines is good",...,@"40.Check if Security system works fine",nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

**For DeSelecting Row**

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

**For Selecting Row**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
```

and by use `[tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];` u get all selected rows `indexpath`.

Also don't forget to enable `Multiple Selection` its `Single` by default